# Files - gof-directory-async.vala:471: Listing directory error:

Tags: pantheon-files

when opening a remote directory (FTP) on Pantheon-files, I get the following message (I opened Pantheon-file from the terminal to get error messages).

> gof-directory-async.vala:471: Listing directory error: La connexion est fermée ftp://user@mywebsite.com/public/www

*La connexion est fermée* translates to *The connexion is closed*

All my FTP connexion don't work any more !
They used to work just a few days ago. I don't have a clue about what to do to fix that.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Are you able to login? If not, check this here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1383755 and this here: https://code.launchpad.net/~jeremywootten/pantheon-files/fix-network-browsing. These are bug reports about similar problems like yours.

Comment: Yes, I am able to login. I can see the root directory. As soon as I drilled down to directories, I get the above error message ! 

PCManFM did not work any more, either ! I assume it's not a Pantheon-files error.

Comment: it looks more like that bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1421345 or this one https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1383755

Answer (score 1):

This error could be a result of an old gvfs package as described here:

[gvfsd-ftp crash](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1421345)

This has been fixed in Ubuntu by updating the gvfs package.

You can try these steps to update gvfs as shown [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1361906/comments/10)

Steps:

- Install the package "debian-archive-keyring":

  sudo apt-get install debian-archive-keyring
- Add the following line at the end of the file "/etc/apt/sources.list":

  deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ unstable main contrib
- Refresh repositories:

  sudo apt-get update
- Update gvfs:

  sudo apt-get install gvfs
- Delete or comment the line previously added in the file "/etc/apt/sources.list".
- Refresh repositories:

  sudo apt-get update

Comment: I did state in a previous comment the bug 1421345, that you mention here.
And I did try the fix that's proposed in the bug comments: however that did not solve anything for me (still, "sudo apt-get install gvfs" did not do anything as gvfs is already install).
If I delete the package gvfs, then it won't install because of dependencies problem.
This fix is for Ubuntu 14.10 !

Still this is weird: I only have this problem, with Freya, all other Ubuntu 14.04 derivatives works fine.