# Can anyone access an FTP Server using Pantheon Files?

Tags: pantheon-files

It does not work for me, on three machines (see [this other question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1972/files-gof-directory-async-vala471-listing-directory-error/2051#2051)).

So I am curious to know whether this is a general Freya bug, or did someone manage to get it working, or that might be due to the collection of software I use ?

Cheers,
L@u

Comment: I have a fresh install of Freya 0.3.1 here and it's working fine. I have successfully access a FTP server, list and upload files via Pantheon Files.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that Files is a file browser, not an FTP app.

There is a native FTP app for elementary OS called [Taxi](https://code.launchpad.net/taxi)

Comment: Well, with any other Linux distribution I can connect to FTP web sites using Files, but also using my text editor to directly modify my files, on the server, without the need of downloading and then uploading back the file.
If I must do that, I might just as well, go back to Windows !

By denying a problem, you don't show much respect to your users !

Answer (score 0):

Work is in progress to improve FTP server (and other remote protocol) handling in Files and hopefully this will land in Loki.  A dedicated app is likely to be remain better than a general purpose file browser however.

Comment: The aim is not only to connect to a FTP server through a file browser but also with any compatible application ... and that includes texte editors !
That means it is possible to work on files remotely as if they were on your local machine ... that's one of the major interest of using Linux !

Comment: FTP is probably not the right protocol for that - as the name suggests it is intended for file transfer.   I have edited files on SMB and AFP servers OK though after using latest Files to open them.

Comment: YES, FTP is the RIGHT protocol to access web server that are hosted remotely.
And this can be done with any other Ubuntu based (or Linux) distribution: there's just something wrong in elementary OS !
Why everybody is just trying to deny the problem instead of solving it !

Comment: Yes, it is working fine with Loki !

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

Not for me. Can't upload files to a remote server in Elementary loki's "Files". Can connect though and save files through the connection via Geany . I currently circumvented the problem by installing and using nautilus. The ftp then works as intended.